# Where does the timeLeft variable reduce?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var timeLeft = 60;
const elem = document.getElementById('timer');

countdown(); // To prevent the timer from starting after a 1 second pause
const timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);

function countdown() {
    if (timeLeft == -1) {
        clearTimeout(timerId); // To stop the timer
    } else {
        elem.innerHTML = timeLeft;
        timeLeft--;
    }

    seconds = 60 - timeLeft; // The time taken to complete the quiz

    if (timeLeft == -1) { // If the timer runs out, all elements will disappear, and ONLY the score will be displayed
        outline.style.display = 'none';
        square.style.display = 'none';
        title.style.display = 'none';
        quizTimer.style.display = 'none';
        displayResult.style.display = '';
        displayResult.textContent = 'Score = ' + score;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Please add a code snippet instead of image.

Comment: its there in the link 'timer js code'

Comment: oh ok I'm sorry, I'm new to this

Comment: It's reduced in `timeLeft--`. Next question is how does it get executed once every second? `setInterval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking:

> Where does the `timeLeft` variable reduce

And you mean:

> Where in the code does the `timeLeft` variable's value decrease

Then I can say it occurs here, where you are post-decrementing the value (it means subtract one, essentially):

```
else {
    elem.innerHTML = timeLeft;
    timeLeft--;
}
```

Comment: oh ok thanks, one more question, why is it "if (timeLeft == -1)" and not "if (timeLeft == 0)"

Comment: I don't know @AbdullahAjmal, there is not enough code context.

Comment: @AbdullahAjmal timeLeft == -1 because at timeLeft ==0, the minute is still very much alive